# Skip a row when printing if certain columns are empty in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I have a sheet with 10 rows and 5 columns. Rows are for products and columns B to E are clients. For example let's say none of the clients want the product in row 5 and 6. How can I prevent those rows from printing?

I played around data filter option but if I choose to exclude empty rows from column C, it hides the empty rows even if other columns have values in them. What I need is to hide the row only if columns B to E are all empty. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try with the data_filter `filter by condition` **>** `custom formula`:*

```js
=counta(B2:E2)<>0
```

**FULL_DATA**

[image]

**AFTER CUSTOM FORMULA FILTER APPLIED**

[image]